# How to check method annotation at runtime in Android?

Tags: java, android, annotations

I'm currently developing a library for Android where I want to make sure certain methods got annotated with my custom annotation. Specifically,

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MustBeAnnotated {

}


public class Hello {

    @MustBeAnnotated
    public void doOne() {
        System.out.println("doOne()");
    }

    @MustBeAnnotated
    public int doTwo() {
        System.out.println("doTwo()");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In pure Java environment, I was able to verify these methods via `main()` method and I'm using [Google Reflection library](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/).

```
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.MethodAnnotationsScanner;
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurationBuilder bd = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        bd.setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.greystripe.sdk"));
        bd.setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner());
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(bd);
        Set<Method> methods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(MustBeAnnotated.class);
        for (Method m : methods) {
            System.out.println(m.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve the same thing in Android environment because there is no such `main()` method provided publicly. The only class I can think of is `Application`, but as a library provider I can't seem to touch this class either. Basically, I want only annotated methods can be called. So if any developer declared a new method without annotation and call it (`hello.doThree()`), they will receive a runtime exception.

```
public class Hello {

    @MustBeAnnotated
    public void doOne() {
        System.out.println("doOne()");
    }

    @MustBeAnnotated
    public int doTwo() {
        System.out.println("doTwo()");
        return 0;
    }


    /**
     * Without annotation, a RuntimeException should be thrown!
     */
    public void doThree() {
        // ...
    }
}



    // ....
    // ...
    Hello hello = new Hello();
    // throw Runtime exception because doThree() has no annotation
    hello.doThree();
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is the problem with Android? It supports reflection.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Using reflection you can check to see if a method has an annotation. How that is going to lead to what you're talking about at the end is ... cloudy, with a chance of you can't do that.

Comment: @Brian: I think my problem is very similar to how you annotate `JavascriptInterface` for java class that can be called on Javascript.

Comment: In Android you can add something like this.
Activity.getClass() and you can check for anotations 
not sure if that's what you want??

Also you can register a handler for the activity lifecycle so you can check the annotation. I used that for class-annotation but that  can help you, i hope

Comment: @Chan I have slightly different use case, let me know if you have some idea about it. I want to read highlighted value from annotation. https://pastebin.com/H8K71Uj5

Comment: @Chan I can add a question for it if you have some idea or we can chat on chatroom.